# How do i add goal tracking circles in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

Hey stackoverflow i'm trying to make 7 goal tracking circles at the bottom of my app, but my app only showing try visually loading circles. i tried everything but nothing seems to be working.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:circular_chart_flutter/circular_chart_flutter.dart';
import 'package:pedometer/pedometer.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

Future<void> _saveSteps(int steps) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String key = DateFormat('yyyyMMdd').format(DateTime.now());
  await prefs.setInt(key, steps);
}

Future<int?> _getStepsForDate(DateTime date) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String key = DateFormat('yyyyMMdd').format(date);
  print("Fetched steps for $key: ${prefs.getInt(key)}");
  return prefs.getInt(key);
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late String _timeString;
  int initSteps = 0;
  double progressValue = 0.0;

  DateTime _currentDate = DateTime.now();

  late GlobalKey<AnimatedCircularChartState> _chartKey;

  List<int?> pastWeekSteps = List.filled(7, null);

  void _loadPastWeekData() async {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      pastWeekSteps[i] =
          await _getStepsForDate(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: i)));
    }
    setState(() {}); // Refresh UI after fetching data
  }

  StreamSubscription<StepCount>? _subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _listenToSteps();
    _timeString = _formatDateTime(DateTime.now());
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => _getTime());

    _chartKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedCircularChartState>();
    _loadStepsForCurrentDay();
    _loadPastWeekData();
  }

  String _formatDateTime(DateTime dateTime) {
    return '${dateTime.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${dateTime.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

  void _getTime() {
    final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    final String formattedDateTime = _formatDateTime(now);
    setState(() {
      _timeString = formattedDateTime;
    });
  }

  void _listenToSteps() async {
    PermissionStatus status = await Permission.activityRecognition.status;

    if (!status.isGranted) {
      status = await Permission.activityRecognition.request();
    }

    if (status.isGranted) {
      try {
        _subscription = Pedometer.stepCountStream.listen(
          _onStepCount,
          onError: _onError,
          onDone: _onDone,
          cancelOnError: true,
        );
      } catch (error) {
        print("Error occurred while trying to fetch step count: $error");
        setState(() {
          initSteps = 0;
        });
      }
    } else {
      print("Permission denied.");
    }
  }

  void _onStepCount(StepCount event) {
    setState(() {
      initSteps = event.steps;
      progressValue = event.steps / 10000;
      _chartKey.currentState?.updateData(
        _getChartData(initSteps / 10000.0),
      );
    });

    _saveSteps(initSteps).then((_) {
      // Now, after saving steps, we can update the past week's steps.
      _updatePastWeekStepsToday(event.steps);
    });
  }

  void _updatePastWeekStepsToday(int steps) {
    DateTime today = DateTime.now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      DateTime date = today.subtract(Duration(days: i));
      if (date.day == today.day) {
        setState(() {
          pastWeekSteps[i] = steps;
        });
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  void _decrementDay() async {
    setState(() {
      _currentDate = _currentDate.subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
    });
    _loadStepsForCurrentDay();
  }

  void _incrementDay() async {
    setState(() {
      _currentDate = _currentDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
    });
    _loadStepsForCurrentDay();
  }

  void _loadStepsForCurrentDay() async {
    int? steps = await _getStepsForDate(_currentDate);
    if (steps != null) {
      setState(() {
        initSteps = steps;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        initSteps = 0; // set it to zero if there's no record for that day
      });
    }
  }

  Widget _buildDayChart(int steps) {
    double progress = steps / 10000.0; // Assuming the goal is always 10k steps
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Icon(Icons.circle_outlined, color: Colors.white, size: 50.0),
        AnimatedCircularChart(
          size: const Size(50.0, 50.0),
          initialChartData: _getChartData(progress),
          chartType: CircularChartType.Radial,
          edgeStyle: SegmentEdgeStyle.round,
          percentageValues: true,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1), // Animation duration
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildWeekStepsWidgets() {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      DateTime date = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: i));
      widgets.add(FutureBuilder<int?>(
        future: _getStepsForDate(date),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  _buildDayChart(snapshot.data!),
                  Text(
                      '${snapshot.data} steps on ${DateFormat('EEEE').format(date)}')
                ],
              );
            }
            return Column(
              children: [
                _buildDayChart(0),
                Text('0 steps on ${DateFormat('EEEE').format(date)}')
              ],
            );
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ));
    }
    return widgets;
  }

  void _onDone() {}

  void _onError(error) {
    print("An error occurred while fetching step count: $error");
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Error'),
        content: Text('An error occurred: $error'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  List<CircularStackEntry> _getChartData(double d) {
    double percentage = d * 100;
    double remainingPercentage = 100.0 - percentage;

    return <CircularStackEntry>[
      CircularStackEntry(
        <CircularSegmentEntry>[
          CircularSegmentEntry(
            percentage,
            Colors.green,
            rankKey: 'completed',
          ),
          CircularSegmentEntry(
            remainingPercentage,
            Colors.black,
            rankKey: 'remaining',
          ),
        ],
        rankKey: 'progress',
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 30.0, 10.0, 0.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      'iCounter',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      _timeString,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 25.0),
              LinearProgressIndicator(
                value: progressValue,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                valueColor: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30.0),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: _decrementDay,
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      size: 60.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                  Text(
                    DateFormat('EEEE').format(_currentDate),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 35.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: _incrementDay,
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      size: 60.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 48),
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  '$initSteps',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 100.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Text(
                'steps today',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30.0),
              Text(
                '$initSteps/10.000s',
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'KCAL: ${initSteps ~/ 20}', // Simple kcal calculation
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 15.0),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'MILES: ${(initSteps / 2000).toStringAsFixed(2)}', // Simple miles calculation
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 15.0),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Minutes: ${initSteps ~/ 100}', // Simple minutes calculation
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 40.0),
              SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: _buildWeekStepsWidgets(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i think i've added all permissions and everything i don't understand what is the problem exactly if someone can help that would much appreciated.

Comment: what is the error you have getting or share the screen shot what you want to need?

Comment: Hi @SubrataDas this is what i'm trying to get:

Comment: you can do that by setting shrinkWrap: true, physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() inside listwidget